# Override the Admin.py file of reusable app in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I basically have 2 external Django app that are overriding the **UserAdmin**  model.
Each one of these will first unregister the UserAdmin model and then register their own, something like this:

```
admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), ExternalAppUserAdmin)
```

I also, in turn, override the UserAdmin:

```
admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), MyAppUserAdmin)
```

The problem is that depending on the order of the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the *settings* file only the last app will actually override the `UserAdmin`.

Most of the times these overriding are just `InlineModelAdmin` inside the AdminUser, so what I've done so far is to import the external app's InlineModelAdmin models and insert them in my own admin.py. For example:

```
from relationships.admin import RelationshipInline
....
class BaseProfileAdminStacked( NestedModelAdmin, GuardedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BaseProfileInline, RelationshipInline,]
....
admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), BaseProfileAdminStacked)
```

But this seems a little hacky to me, because for example:

- The first external app will unregister the UserAdmin, then register it again with its own customization
- The second external app will do the same, actually overriding the first one
- My own app should then import all the AdminInline from the external apps and include them in my own registration of the UserAdmin

Isn't this a waste of effort? Do you have a better idea to do so?

Comment: Maybe that is because you are unregistering it twice. What if you take out the second `unregister`?

Comment: @dan-klasson nope, it throws a "AlreadyRegistered" exception

Comment: also remove it from `installed apps` and then unregister

Comment: Its not perfect but seems fine. If you get a better way out do post it here.